# structure of classes in css - suggestions?

Tags: html, css, class, fonts

Trying to organize elements within my website in order not to get lost, but since I do it for the very first time, I'd like to ask your opinion. Have a look at the image, and let me know whether such classes naming makes sense semantic-wise and efficiency-wise:

[image]

I have several divs like that one on my website and they differ in terms of font size, placement of elements etc, which is why I decided to use tree-structure when giving names to the classes.

You think this is a good idea or you'd rather do it differently?

Comment: Do you need to repeat business-card in each of your class names? I guess it makes sense but since it's all going to be children of a node with class businesscard anyway then you could probably shorten the names with no danger of conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've got a hierarchical structure, why not use it in CSS as well, as such I'd do it as follows:

```
.businesscard {}
.businesscard .details {}
.businesscard .details .name {}
.businesscard .details .connector {}
.businesscard .details .date {}
.businesscard .title {}
.businesscard .content {}
.businesscard .progress {}
```

As such this approach is easier translatable to LESS/SCSS than the one with -

```
.businesscard {
 .details {
  .name {}
  .connector {}
  .date {}
 }
 .title {}
 .content {}
 .progress {}
}
```

Additionally if you were to create a, let's say red business card. One approach would be to add it on the top container as `class='red businesscard'`, but would it then be consistent with the scheme you've created? If you were to create a red business card that has a different look for the top container, but rest stays the same, with your given scheme it would be `class='red-businesscard'`, but then it would be inconsistent with the naming of  other containers.

Comment: Thanks guys! So let me get that clear - using the structure as you both mentioned, I can have a class "content" that has different values, depending on the div in which it's placed, as long as I stick to hierarchical structure? Ie. `.businesscard1 .content {color:red}` and `.businesscard2 .content {color: blue}`? In html I'd have to go for `class="businesscard1 content"`?

Comment: Yes, yes, no - in html you'd have it as `<div class='businesscard1'><div class='content'></div></div>`

Comment: Ah, obviously! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `class="content"` etc. and reflect your tree structure using descendant selectors. E.g.

```
#businesscard .content { /*...*/ }
#businesscard .details { /*...*/ }
```

etc.

This also gives you the flexibility to apply styles to similar elements across the page, e.g.

```
.content { /*...*/ }
.details { /*...*/ }
```

If you're likely to use more than one `businesscard` div, you should use a class instead of the id, e.g.

```
.businesscard .content { /*...*/ }
.businesscard .details { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response too, really appreciate it